# How to use suse linux as a small router

Tags: linux, router, opensuse

I have 2 subnets 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24 and one suse linux server. The linux has 2 interfaces, eth0 and eth1. 
 I want to configure the suse linux server as a router so that I can make these 2 subnets communicate with each other.

These are my steps：

1. set the linux eth0 ip as 192.160.1.254，eth1 ip 192.168.2.254
2. add route in linux：

   ```
   route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0 
   route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth1
   ```
3. set 192.168.1.0/24 gw as 192.168.1.254，and 192.168.2.0/24 gw as 192.168.2.254

I am not sure if this will work or not? Or is there some step I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

You need at least one other step:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

I don't think you need the explicit route commands above.  Simply setting up the two interfaces and allowing forwarding should satisfy your routing requirement.

Check the output of your routing table with:

```
netstat -rn
```

Comment: Agreed, there is no need for the extra routing rules.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used SuSE in many years but here is a how-to from Novell that should get you up and running if you are using X.
http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11505.html

If you are not using X, follow this tutorial (although some files may be in different places on SuSE):
http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/